# GWT application crawler error undefined.cache.js

Tags: google-crawlers, deferred-binding

I have a GWT application http://islamart.tn which fails on google crawling : 
 The 'fetch as google' feature fails with a 'partial' status saying that it can't find  undefined.cache.js

After some research, I found that this js is the app js when the user.agent is not recognized

I therefore changed my

> UserAgentPropertyGenerator.UserAgent

enum value for gecko to recognize google bot:

```
 gecko1_8("return (ua.indexOf('Googlebot') || ua.indexOf('gecko') != -1 || docMode >= 11);");
```

In my core GWT module I naturally added the line :

```
<property-provider name="user.agent" generator="fr.onevu.vume.client.common.UserAgentPropertyGenerator"/>
```

I installed 'Chrome UA spoofer" to emulate the Googlebot user.agent request, and  what happened is that now I have a warning at startup saying that the runtime value safari is different than the compile time gecko_18

I still see some checking runtime code in the generated js

```
{$stackDepth_0=stackIndex_0-1;return 'gecko1_8'}$stackDepth_0=stackIndex_0-1;return 'unknown'}
```

but those files are very large, and I don't know from which classes they are generated.

Additionally, I had to fall back to the version 2.6.1 since compilation with 2.8.1RC1 and 2.7.0 don't finish the job (for some reason I don't have the time to investigate now)

Any ideas please?...

I need an answer to one of these questions :

- How to personalize the runtime user agent check generated code ?
- How to make googlebot use the gecko_18 version of my app ?
  [image]

Comment: p.s : phantomjs also fails as the google crawler

Comment: Why is this tagged "deferred"? If you suspect the problem concerns Deferreds/Promises, then further explanation is required on that point.

Comment: There's a mecanism called 'deferred-binding' in GWT, no tag is available for that, so I took the nearest one to describe the problem